# How to find out index of item in array after sorting

Tags: java, sorting, time-complexity

i have int array where is for example {7,3,5,4} and i want to sorted them, but i want to find out index of item before sorting. I don't want to finding the item in unsorted array because it is so slow (Complexity **O(n^2)**). Is there any way how to do that?

Comment: Build a new array of objects, where the object has the value and the original index, then sort the new array by value. The sorted result will then have the original index for each value.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! It's not totally clear what you're asking - do you want to find the item before sorting, or after sorting? Are you looking for a search/sort with better time complexity?

Comment: Andreas's answer is the solution of my proublem, thanks

Comment: Linear search on unsorted arrays has an O(n) complexity, not O(n^2).

Comment: but i want to finding out on each item in unsorted item so it is O(n^2) ;) @NándorElődFekete

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to keep track of 2 arrays, what I like to do in these cases is create a `TreeMap` where the key is the value of the array and the value is the index of the array. Just giving you another variation from the comments. Something like this:

```
int[] intArray = { 7, 3, 5, 4 };
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
for(int i=0; i<intArray.length; i++){
    map.put(intArray[i], i);
}
//prints numbers in order with orginal index
for(int key : map.keySet()){
    System.out.println("Number "+key);
    System.out.println("Orginal index "+map.get(key));
}
```

Output:

```
Number 3
Orginal index 1
Number 4
Orginal index 3
Number 5
Orginal index 2
Number 7
Orginal index 0
```